# bsearch on array sorted in descending order

Tags: c, binary-search, libc, bsearch

I have an array which is sorted in descending order, with no duplicates. Can I perform binary search on it using bsearch function in libc ? To do this, do I need to alter the compare function that I am passing to it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use `bsearch`.  You will need to make sure your `compare` function agrees with the sort order of your array.  In your case that might mean logically inverting the normal ascending/equal/descending order.

Comment: Thanks. SO I just reverse my comparison function and it should work